# How to return null rows from mysql_num_rows?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following mysql query that returns data in a JSON.  What's the best way to check if there are 0 records, and return that fact?

```
$row_num = mysql_num_rows($rslt);
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
    $data[] = $row;     
}   
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: I would leave it exactly the same. count rows with javascript.

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are [now deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row_num = mysql_num_rows($rslt);
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
    $data[] = $row;     
}   
if(!$data){
   echo "This is the government. We have removed your database!";
} else {
    echo json_encode( $data );
}
```